# Is there a way to get SoundPlayer to work or is there an alternative?

Tags: mono

I am using the [Raspbian “wheezy”](http://www.raspbian.org/) image and I copied over a wav file and played it successfully doing:

```
aplay test.wav
```

So then I knocked up this little console application:

```
using System;
using System.Media;
using System.IO;

namespace SoundPlayingTest
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            using(var file = new FileStream("test.wav", 
                FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                var player = new SoundPlayer(file);
                player.PlaySync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expected that to play the wav just like `aplay` but it finishes (with no error) and I hear nothing from the headphones I have plugged in.

I found this thread "[System.Media.SoundPlayer silent](http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/System-Media-SoundPlayer-silent-td1529831.html)" that suggested it wasn't working but was fixed and the workaround suggested there is exactly what I am doing so I am not really any further.

To give some further information I ran:

```
mono --version
```

And this was the result:

```
Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-5)
Copyright (C) 2002-2011 Novell, Inc, Xamarin, Inc and Contributors.     www.mono-project.com
TLS:           __thread
SIGSEGV:       normal
Notifications: epoll
Architecture:  armel,vfp
Disabled:      none
Misc:          softdebug 
LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)
```

So, is it possible to get `SoundPlayer` to work (it should play a wav file right?) or is there some alternative I can use in order to play a sound file from mono running on the PI?

(by the way, I installed mono by doing `sudo apt-get install mono-complete` so I guess I am not missing any dependencies)

Comment: What language is that?

Comment: @Jivings I believe that is C#

Comment: yes, that is correct - c sharp

Comment: I have just tried this exact code on my Raspberry Pi with Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.8 (Debian 3.2.8+dfsg-4+rpi1) and Raspbian version 3.12.22+ #691 PREEMPT and it appears to work, however at the end of the file it segfaults unless you run it as root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are allot of sound issues with the Raspberry Pi - and I `mono` on Pi(or any Linux actually) was no exception.

There [has been an issue with this](https://github.com/mono/mono/pull/486) and it is resolved in the master repo.

How to solve the problem? You can try and build mono from the latest source or wait a while until it is pushed into the next update. But it seems mono on "wheezy"  does not support audio because ...

> p/invokes are broken on raspbian. especially if floating point values are involved

So sources have suggested :

> run any non-hard-float os on the pi. or wait for hf support in mono 3.0 packages in debian experimental. couple of weeks for that, imho.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample code played for me, however if I run my console app as sudo, the SSH session hangs and I need to start a new one.

This doesn't happen if not sudo (I need sudo to access i2c)

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ mono --version
Mono Runtime Engine version 3.2.7 (master/d7ce227 Monday 23 December  21:49:08 EST 2013)
Copyright (C) 2002-2013 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       normal
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  armel,vfp+hard
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
        GC:            sgen
```

I also get some audio errors to std out but otherwise the sound plays

```
*** glibc detected *** mono: double free or corruption (!prev): 0x01b862a8 ***
Stacktrace:

  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Mono.Audio.AlsaDevice.snd_pcm_hw_params_free (intptr) <0xffffffff>
  at Mono.Audio.AlsaDevice.Dispose (bool) <0x0004f>
  at Mono.Audio.AlsaDevice.Finalize () <0x00027>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_virtual_void__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>
```

Comment: The method of process.start aplay works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288985/how-to-make-mono-beep-or-play-sound-under-64-bit-linux

Comment: FYI, we found an issue in the mono implementation of Mono.Audio.AlsaDevice where it was not nulling out pointers that it was freeing with snd_pcm_XXX_free calls.  We got this same call stack.  See https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=24109 for the patch (which has been accepted).

Comment: fantastic - great work!

Comment: Chrish, this problem was fixed around 3.10.x. But came back at the latest version 4+ :(